# Sending log to remote MSMQ

Tags: nlog

I installed NLog version 2 and sending to a remote MSMQ is not working. Do I have the config setup properly?

```
  <nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="MSMQ" name="MSMQLog" useXmlEncoding="true" queue="FormatName:DIRECT=OS:server01\private$\test_log" recoverable="true" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="MSMQLog" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

I installed MSMQ on my local box and the server I'm sending the message too. NLog doesn't throw any exceptions (they are turned on). I don't see anything in the outgoing mailbox on my local machine.

I am able to send to the queue by using the following code.

```
using (var queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:server01\private$\tasi_log")) 
                { 
                    var message = new Message("TEST"); 
                    message.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter(); 
                    queue.Send(message); 
                }
```

Does NLog work with remote queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried sending to a public queue and it still didn't work using NLog. So, I looked at the NLog.Extended source code and I found this method.

```
protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
        { 
            if (this.Queue == null) 
            { 
                return; 
            } 

            string queue = this.Queue.Render(logEvent); 

            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queue)) 
            { 
                if (this.CreateQueueIfNotExists) 
                { 
                    MessageQueue.Create(queue); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 
            } 

            using (MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(queue)) 
            { 
                Message msg = this.PrepareMessage(logEvent); 
                if (msg != null) 
                { 
                    mq.Send(msg); 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

I commented out the following if statement and it now sends to remote queues. Can someone verify this? Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queue)) 
            { 
                if (this.CreateQueueIfNotExists) 
                { 
                    MessageQueue.Create(queue); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    return; 
                } 
            }
```